# why meta description is catching empty even if it is filled in view.yml?

Tags: symfony1, seo, meta-tags

I have a page where its meta-contents are deriving from view.yml file.

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="summer jobs" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
```

In view.yml file it is as below:

```
summerjobsSuccess:
  has_layout:     on
  layout:         layoutreg
  stylesheets:    [common]
  metas:
    title:        Summer Jobs for Students
    robots:       index, follow
    description:  Find the best summer jobs here including: working abroad, summer camp jobs, summer festival jobs, and student summer jobs in retail or telesales
    keywords:     summer jobs
    language:     en
```

I looked for spacing and it seems perfect.
What may be the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you have a colon (`:`) in your description - you need to enclose the string in quotes :

```
description:  'Find the best summer jobs here including: working abroad, summer camp jobs, summer festival jobs, and student summer jobs in retail or telesales'
```

Comment: Hi .. I removed the colon and tested in local. It is working. But its nor working on live server.